# Asynchronous iterable mapping in Dart

Tags: dart

Can I map some Iterable using async mapping function? Maybe it is a bug, that this code prints list of _Future imidiately, not ints after 1 or 5 seconds?

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<int> foo(int i) {
  var c = new Completer();
  new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 1), () => c.complete(i));
  return c.future;
}

main() {
  var list = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var mappedList = list.map((i) async => await foo(i));
  print(mappedList);
}
```

Comment: This won't work for inferred list, this just had to work because the list is the same as `List<dynamic>`, once the var is inferred with the same type as the RHS result, it fails.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The expression `(i) async => await foo(i)` still returns a future. You can use `Future.wait(mappedList)` to wait till all created futures are completed.

Comment: So it should be `List mappedList = await Future.wait(list.map((i) async => await foo(i)));`.

Comment: This also works: `List mappedList = await Future.wait(list.map((i) => foo(i)));`, because it is able to detect the returned mapped value as a `Future` without the need to wait.

Answer (score 15):

Your misunderstanding is that async functions return a `Future`, not a value. `await` does not convert async to sync.

```
var mappedList = list.map(
  (i) async => await foo(i) // Returns a Future, not an int
);
```

You are printing are the Futures returned by `(i) async => await foo(i)`.

Those Futures complete when the chain of Futures within them complete. When the Timer fires: `foo()` completes, then `await foo(i)`, then your mapping function.

Compare with:

```
main() async {
  List<int> list = [1,2,3,4,5];
  Iterable<Future<int>> mapped;

  // Prints ints 1 second apart
  mapped = list.map((i) => foo(i));
  for(Future<int> f in mapped) {
    print(await f);
  }

  // Prints ints all at once, after 1 second wait
  mapped = list.map((i) => foo(i));
  for(Future<int> f in mapped) {
    f.then(print);
  }
}
```

On Dartpad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/151949be67c0cdc0c54742113c98b291

Some things to note:

`List.map()` returns a *lazy `Iterable`* (not a `List`) which means the mapping function isn't called until the `Iterable` is iterated through.

The first loop waits for each `Future` to complete before printing and moving on to the next item in the `Iterable`, the mapping function for the next item (and hence `foo()`) is called *after* printing each value, so values are printed at 1 second intervals.

The second loop iterates through the `Iterable` immediately, setting up a print function to execute after each `Future` completes. 5 instances of function foo() are called at once, which all return approximately 1 second later, then all 5 values are printed.

Answer (score 14):

other answers didn't really work in my case, ended up using `rxdart`'s `asyncMap` like this :

```
Observable.fromIterable(list)
      .asyncMap((item) => foo(item))
      .toList();
```

Edit: `Observable` class has been discontinued since [rxdart 0.23.0](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart#0230), you can use [Streams](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) instead like this:

```
Stream
 .fromIterable(list)
 .asyncMap((item) => foo(item))
 .toList();
```

Answer (score 13):

Adding some type will explain what's going on:

```dart
main() async {
  var list = [1,2,3,4,5];
  Iterable<Future<int>> mappedList = list.map((i) async => await foo(i));
  print(mappedList); // you print an Iterable of Future 

  // to get the list of int you have to do the following
  Future<List<int>> futureList = Future.wait(mappedList);
  List<int> result = await futureList;
  print(result);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get Exception at result = await futureList. Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError (Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null)

Answer (score 8):

With today's Dart, there's no problem. Forget `map`, just build your list directly:

```
final list = [for (final item in items) await buildAsync(item)];
```

Comment: it seems not working in parallel

Comment: @Yin This is a simple sequential for-loop, so it will wait on each iteration. To maximize parallelization of I/O bound tasks, you should first create a list of futures, then await those futures. E.g., `final futures = items.map((item) => buildAsync(item)).toList(); final list = [for (final future in futures) await future]`. The last line can also be written `final list = Future.wait(futures)`.