# List.map returns List<Future>

Tags: flutter, dart

I got a class for handling `SharePreferences`

```dart
class SharedPreferencesUtils {    
  static Future<String> getSharedPreference(String key) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString(key);
  }
}
```

I try to use this class from another class to get all my sharedPreferences with this method:

```dart
void getAllPrefs() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  var keyList = prefs.getKeys().toList();
  var valueList = keyList.map((key) async {
    String value = await SharedPreferencesUtils.getSharedPreference(key);
    return value;
  }).toList();
  print("KEY LIST IS $keyList");
  print("VALUE LIST IS $valueList");
}
```

And, while the keyList works well, the valueList just returns:

```
VALUE LIST IS [Instance of 'Future<String>', Instance of 'Future<String>', Instance of 'Future<String>', Instance of 'Future<String>', Instance of 'Future<String>', Instance of 'Future<String>', Instance of 'Future<String>', Instance of 'Future<String>', Instance of 'Future<String>', Instance of 'Future<String>']
```

I don't really get why I am not getting the actual `String` value corresponding to the `key`, as I understood `Futures`, in this case, the execution should `await` until the var `value` gets the String value that I am asking for.....am I wrong?

Note: there are values stored in `SharedPreferences`, that is for sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous iterable mapping in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015671/asynchronous-iterable-mapping-in-dart)

Comment: CreativeCreator's excellent first paragraph is key to understanding why you got a list of futures. However, don't forget that the only thing that is async about shared preferences is getting the initial instance. You could therefore refactor `getSharedPreference` to not be async by simply passing in the shared preferences instance, and you could call it 'normally'. `String getSharedPreference(String key, SharedPreferences instance) => instance.getString(key);` At that point, you barely need it and can inline it! Also, avoid classes with just static functions. Use top level functions instead.

Comment: @RichardHeap do you mind explain why to avoid class with static methods?, feels more clean to group all sharedPreferences functions in a class for that purpose, better than using top-level functions. Thinking about SOLID principles now...but might be wrong.

Comment: It's more Darty. See https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_classes_with_only_static_members.html It's also a performance killer in Dart2JS, but you probably don't care about that.

Comment: aha i see ok!, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good one :)

I will only need to mention one key concept and you will see why this is happening: *Any **`async`** function returns a **`Future`***.
In your case, the `map` call uses an `async` callback and hence the values in your lists are `Future`s.

---

There is a helper in the `Future` class: [`Future.wait`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html)

You can simply pass your `Iterable` to it and it will return a list with resolved futures:

```dart
Future<void> getAllPrefs() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  final keyList = prefs.getKeys().toList();

  final valueList = await Future.wait(keyList.map((key) async {
    String value = await SharedPreferencesUtils.getSharedPreference(key);
    return value;
  }));

  print("KEY LIST IS $keyList");
  print("VALUE LIST IS $valueList");
}
```

---

How do you do it without the helper? Well, not use `map` because it requires a callback, but you need to stay in the same scope if you want to get rid of `Future` values as any outside function would need to be `async`. So here you go:

```dart
Future<void> getAllPrefs() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  final keyList = prefs.getKeys().toList();

  final valueList = List<String>(keyList.length);
  for (int i = 0; i < valueList.length; i++) 
    valueList[i] = await SharedPreferencesUtils.getSharedPreference(keyList[i]);

  print("KEY LIST IS $keyList");
  print("VALUE LIST IS $valueList");
}
```

One practice that helps you to remember that all `async` functions return futures is using `Future<void>` as the return type instead.

---

If you use `Future.wait`, i.e. still use your `map` call, you can make it a lot more concise like this:

```dart
await Future.wait(keyList.map(SharedPreferencesUtils.getSharedPreferences));
```

You can just use `keyList.map(SharedPreferencesUtils.getSharedPreferences)` because `getSharedPreferences` already takes a `String` and returns a `Future<String>`, which is equivalent to what you were doing before :)

Comment: very good explanation, also appreciate that you provide 2 options, thanks!

Comment: however, your first option using Future.wait, (copied and pasted from your code) still gives as an output VALUE LIST IS Instance of 'Future<List<String>>' I might be doing something else wrong

Comment: second option with for loop works fine, I already tested that before, just still wondering why it does not work with map

Comment: @codeKiller Sorry, I missed the `await` keyword. You need to `await` `Future.wait` because it obviously needs to be an `async` function to convert the values from future values.

Comment: yeah figured it out, was this missing await at the beginning of the future, looks like a bit overload of awaits with that option, but it works indeed, thanks.