# Dart List doesnt get updated with forEach loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this [package](https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts) to retrieve device's contacts. The lib retrieve 427 contacts and I want to loop the whole list so that I can create another list and send it to the back-end. The problem is looping does not work this the function return before looping is completed.

Here the function I use:

```dart
  Future<QueryResult> uploadContacts() async {
    final List<Contact> rawContacts =
        (await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false)).toList();
    List<ContactInput> contactsListInput;

    print('contactsListInput length: ${rawContacts.length}');
    
    rawContacts.forEach((contact) {
      print('contact: $contact'); //PRINTED JUST ONCE

      //Contact can have more than 1 number. We need them all
      contact.phones.forEach((phone) {
        final contactInput =
            ContactInput(name: contact.displayName, phone: phone.value);

        contactsListInput.add(contactInput);
      });
    });

    print('contactsListInput length: ${contactsListInput.length}'); //NEVER PRINT ANYTHING

    final ContactsListInput input =
        ContactsListInput(contacts: contactsListInput);

    final MutationOptions _options = MutationOptions(
        document: SyncContactsMutation().document,
        variables: SyncContactsArguments(input: input).toJson());

    return client.mutate(_options);
  }
```

I have also tried using for loop and the same thing happened.

```dart
    for (int i = 0; i < rawContacts.length; i++) {
      final contact = rawContacts[i];

      final contactInput =
      ContactInput(name: contact.displayName, phone: contact.phones.first.value);

      contactsListInput.add(contactInput);
    }
    print('contactsListInput length: ${contactsListInput.length}'); //NEVER CALLED
```

And I also tried  Future.forEach

```dart
    await Future.forEach(rawContacts, (contact) async {
      print('contact: $contact');

      //Since contact can have more than one number we loop them too.
      await Future.forEach(contact.phones, (phone) async {
        final contactInput =
            ContactInput(name: contact.displayName, phone: phone.value);

        contactsListInput.add(contactInput);
      });
    });
```

How to fix this? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `List<ContactInput> contactsListInput;` is `null` - you cannot call `contactsListInput.add(contactInput);` when `contactsListInput` is null - you have to initialize that list - btw you dont need those `forEach` / `add` etc - simply use `Iterable.map()` /  `Itarable.expand()` methods

Comment: Looks to me like your `contactsListInput` List is never initialized to a value. You might be getting exceptions happening

Comment: as simple as: `rawContacts.expand((contact) => contact.phones.map((phone) => ContactInput(name: contact.displayName, phone: phone)))`

Comment: @pskink thanks. Of course the problem was not initializing it.

Comment: and as i said: you dont need that list at all (and two `forEach` loops): just use `expand()` / `map()` methods

Comment: @I removed it. Would you mind answering it?

Comment: great, post a self answer then

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it as

```dart
  Future<QueryResult> uploadContacts() async {
    final Iterable<Contact> rawContacts =
        (await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false));

    final Iterable<ContactInput> contacts = rawContacts.expand((contact) => contact.phones.map(
        (phone) =>
            ContactInput(name: contact.displayName, phone: phone.value)));

    final input = ContactsListInput(contacts: contacts);

    final MutationOptions _options = MutationOptions(
        document: SyncContactsMutation().document,
        variables: SyncContactsArguments(input: input).toJson());

    return client.mutate(_options);
  }
```

Credit goes to @pskink  and @loganrussell48

Comment: btw if `ContactsListInput` accepts `contacts` as `Iterable` then you dont need `.asList()` - but of course if `ContactsListInput.contacts` are `List` you have to add `asList()`

Comment: Now I need to format phone number by calling ```await formatPhone(phone.value);``` in map function. This method returns string when phone is valid and null otherwise. Problem is that it returns Future. I have trouble calling inside map. Any suggestion

Comment: seems you need `Future.wait` (or `Future.forEach` but imho `wait` is better in that case)

Comment: ```await Future.forEach(contacts, (ContactInput contact) async {
      final phone = await formatPhone(contact.phone);
      if (phone != null) {
        final input = ContactInput(name: contact.name, phone: phone);
        contactInputs.add(input);
      }
    });````

Comment: I use forEach I just wondering if I could chain something in after map/in mao. Thank anyway

Comment: *var input = [500, 3000, 1000];
  var mapped = input.map((i) async {
    var res = await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: i), () => i / 10);
    return 'result of $i = $res';
  });
  print(mapped);
  print(await Future.wait(mapped));* - here i `await` for `Future.delayed` you need to `await` for `formatPhone` - the main idea is to use "async map" - like: `map((i) async { ...` and `Future.wait` that waits for whole `Iterable`

Comment: just found the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38015671/2252830

Answer (score 0):

You should use it as a dynamic type object. Try something like this:

```
(event.snapshot.value as dynamic).forEach()
```

Try and see if it works.