# Dart Map.map() using async

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Dart Map() which I want to perform a .map() operation on to turn it into a second map. However, this conversion requires an *await* call. How might I do this in Dart? The below gives me an error of course, but how does one achieve this **in one line**?

```
Map secondMap = firstMap.map((key, value) async => MapEntry("key", await someAsyncFunction()))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous iterable mapping in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015671/asynchronous-iterable-mapping-in-dart)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I want to map() a Map, not a List :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
final secondMap = Map.fromEntries(await Future.wait(firstMap.entries.map((entry) async => MapEntry(entry.key, await someAsyncFunction()))));
```